# htaccess redirect to full path url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to create redirect from url with .php and "/" at the end to same url but without "/" and all symbols after.

Example: `/folder/page1.php/xcxc` to `/folder/page1.php`

I write this rule in my htaccess file:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php/
  RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Seems it works good, except it leads to full path `"http://<my_domain>/var/www/<domain_name>/public_html/folder/page1.php"`

How can I remove "/var/www/domain_name/public_html/" from url?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I need to create redirect from any address not from only /folder/

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```